# Fragment becomes ghost after orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with understanding how Android works. Can you help me?
I had connected my fragment to an activity via XML.

```
<fragment android:name="com.unimusic.mediaPlayerControlBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/mediaPlayerControlBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
```

In fragment class I am getting mainActivity class and giving it an instance of fragment like this:

```
//Fragment
@Override
    public void onResume (){
        super.onResume();
        mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        mainActivity.setFragment(this);
    }
//Activity
public void setFragment(mediaPlayerControlBar f){
        frag = f;
        Log.d("FRAG", "SET");
    }
```

And everything works fine. But when I rotate the screen a new "untouched" fragment appears, but it frag.getView() is null. getFragments() list is null. findFragmentById() is null too. So, how can I acces this new fragment?

Let me know if you need any more code, I'll update this post as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save Fragment instance state, because when orientation changes the activity and fragment is recreated.

1. In the fragment you need to save instance state by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onActivityCreated()`
2. In the activity you have to save fragment's state in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onCreate()`

Comment: really useful answer. it help me lot